# how to kill progress dialog in android

Tags: android

I have two Activities In Activity i am calling async task which consists of progress bar is loading util task completed if task completes it disappears.when it click on First Activity screen Activity is loaded When I click on back button from second Actvity it is moving first actvity but progress bar is loading and not dismissed please help to disable progress bar in firstactvity when back button in second Actvity

Comment: Can you add your code for how and where you're starting the progress dialog?

Comment: Post your code here..

Answer (score 3):

What I understood from your question is you want to hide/remove the progress bar from the screen when the other activity appears, you can remove it in the onPause() of the current activity.

**For Example:**

You are in `Activity B` and the progress bar is still on the screen. Now when you go back to `Activity A` before the task is completed, you can remove the progress bar in `onPause` method of the `Activity B`:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();

  progressBar.dismiss();
}
```

make sure you create the progress bar object outside any other method so that its scope is global, so that you can access it in both AsyncTask extended class  and in onPause().

If you want to hide it when the task you are doing in `AsyncTask` is done, you can remove it in `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ProgressDialog as I would assume you are, you can call setCancelable(true) on your instance, then it will dismiss upon back presses.